# RecyclerView null object reference error when repopulate

Tags: java, android-recyclerview

I am having an error with `RecyclerView` where `RecyclerView` works fine on the first run but if I push get_data button again to change the data list randomly it does not always on the second attempt may on the third instance or fourth or fifth it causes the app to crash. Errors are also random like

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.setExactMeasureSpecsFrom(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView)' on a null object reference
```

or

```
RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State)' on a null object reference
```

etc. I am unable to find exact problem.

```
public class DCU_Reading_byTask extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText taskid_edt;
    private APIInterface apiInterface;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    RecyclerView recycler_view_grid_meter_list;
    String DCU = "";
    String group_id, user_id;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    TextView textView_lat;
    Button Send_Data_btn, get_data_btn, back_btn;
    int send_counter = 0;

    DatabaseHandler databaseHandler;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    TextView Uart_read;
    WBInteraction wbInteraction;
    String URL = "Url here";
    ArrayList<dcumetedata> modelRecyclerArrayList;
    ArrayList<dcumetedata> sortedlist = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment;
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_d_c_u__reading_by_task, container, false);
   
        find_view_by_id(view);
        set_on_click_litioner();
        pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("my_pref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        DCU = pref.getString("DCU_code", "DCU");
        textView_lat.setText("DCU no.: " + DCU);

       


        

        return view;
    }

    public void find_view_by_id(View view) {
        recycler_view_grid_meter_list = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_grid_meter_list);
        textView_lat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView_lat);
        Send_Data_btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Send_Data_btn);
        Uart_read = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.receivedatatxt);
        taskid_edt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.taskid_edittext);
        get_data_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.get_data_btn);
        back_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.back_btn);


    }

    public void set_on_click_litioner() {
        Send_Data_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        taskid_edt.setOnClickListener(this);
        get_data_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        back_btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        final android.net.ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((android.net.ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(android.content.Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
        return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            
  

            case R.id.get_data_btn:
                
      
                 if (taskid_edt.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please Enter Task ID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    AsyncTask1 asyntask = new AsyncTask1();
                    asyntask.execute();
                }
                break;


            case R.id.Send_Data_btn:

                senddata();

                break;
        }
    }


    private class AsyncTask1 extends android.os.AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            ArrayList<String> wait = new ArrayList<String>();
            wait.add("PLEASE WAIT......");
            Empty_Adpater adapter = new Empty_Adpater(getContext(), wait);
            recycler_view_grid_meter_list.setAdapter(adapter);
            recycler_view_grid_meter_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));


            wbInteraction.GetDataList(getContext(), taskid_edt.getText().toString(), new WBInteraction.OnGetDataListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChanged(ArrayList<WBInteraction.meterData> list, String mes) {

                    if (!(list == null)) {
                        if (list.size() > 1) {


                             modelRecyclerArrayList = new ArrayList<dcumetedata>();
                            dcumetedata modelRecycler = new dcumetedata();
                            if (!(list == null)) {
                                int j = 0;
                                int count = list.size();
                                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                                    String device = list.get(i).getDeviceCode();
                                    Log.e("DCU: ", DCU);
                                    Log.e("device: ", device);

                                    if (device.equals(DCU)) {
                                        j++;


                                        modelRecycler.setAnalysis(list.get(i).getAnalysis());
                                        modelRecycler.setBattery(list.get(i).getBattery());
                                        modelRecycler.setCommType(list.get(i).getCommType());
                                        modelRecycler.setCommunicationAddress(list.get(i).getCommunicationAddress());
                                        modelRecycler.setDataStr(list.get(i).getDataStr());
                                        modelRecycler.setDeviceCode(list.get(i).getDeviceCode());
                                        modelRecycler.setFreezeDate(list.get(i).getFreezeDate());
                                        modelRecycler.setGasVolume(list.get(i).getGasVolume());
                                        modelRecycler.setMeterRTC(list.get(i).getMeterRTC());
                                        modelRecycler.setNetID(list.get(i).getNetID());
                                        modelRecycler.setRSSI(list.get(i).getRSSI());
                                        modelRecycler.setState(list.get(i).getState());
                                        modelRecycler.setDate(list.get(i).getDate().toString());

                                        modelRecyclerArrayList.add(modelRecycler);

                                    }

                                }
                                if (j == 0) {
                     Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No data for this DCU no.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                      DCUListAdapter adapter = new DCUListAdapter(getContext(), modelRecyclerArrayList);
                                recycler_view_grid_meter_list.setAdapter(adapter);
                                recycler_view_grid_meter_list.setLayoutManager(new 
                                LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));


                            }


                               
                        } else {
                            ArrayList<dcumetedata> modelRecyclerArrayList = new ArrayList<dcumetedata>();
                            DCUListAdapter adapter = new DCUListAdapter(getContext(), modelRecyclerArrayList);
                            recycler_view_grid_meter_list.setAdapter(adapter);
                            recycler_view_grid_meter_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }


                    } else {
                        ArrayList<dcumetedata> modelRecyclerArrayList = new ArrayList<dcumetedata>();
                        DCUListAdapter adapter = new DCUListAdapter(getContext(), modelRecyclerArrayList);
                        recycler_view_grid_meter_list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        recycler_view_grid_meter_list.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("Data List is null", "");

                    }

                }
            });


            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    
}
```

Recycler Adapter:

```
public class DCUListAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<DCUListAdapter.viewholder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<dcumetedata> dataModelArrayList;

    public DCUListAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<dcumetedata> dataModelArrayList) {

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(ctx);
        this.dataModelArrayList = dataModelArrayList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyler_item, viewGroup, false);
        viewholder holder = new viewholder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewholder viewholder, int i) {
        viewholder.Analysis.setText("Analysis:" + dataModelArrayList.get(i).getAnalysis());
        viewholder.Battery.setText("Battery: " + dataModelArrayList.get(i).getBattery());
        viewholder.CommType.setText("Comm. Type: " + dataModelArrayList.get(i).getCommType());
        viewholder.CommunicationAddres.setText("Comm. Addrs: " + dataModelArrayList.get(i).getCommunicationAddress());
        viewholder.DataSt.setText("Data: " + dataModelArrayList.get(i).getDataStr());
        viewholder.Date.setText("Date: " + dataModelArrayList.get(i).getDate());
        viewholder.DeviceCode.setText("DCU no.: " + dataModelArrayList.get(i).getDeviceCode());
        viewholder.FreezeDate.setText("Freeze Data: " + dataModelArrayList.get(i).getFreezeDate());
        viewholder.GasVolume.setText("Gas Vol.: " + dataModelArrayList.get(i).getGasVolume());
        viewholder.MeterRTC.setText("Meter RTC: " + dataModelArrayList.get(i).getMeterRTC());
        viewholder.NetID.setText("Net ID: " + dataModelArrayList.get(i).getNetID());
        viewholder.RSSI.setText("RSSI: " + dataModelArrayList.get(i).getRSSI());
        viewholder.State.setText("State: " + dataModelArrayList.get(i).getState());

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {return dataModelArrayList.size();}


    class viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView Analysis, Battery, CommType, CommunicationAddres, DataSt,Date,DeviceCode,FreezeDate,GasVolume,MeterRTC,NetID,RSSI,State;


        public viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Analysis = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Analysis);
            Battery = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Battery);
            CommunicationAddres = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CommunicationAddres);
            DataSt = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.DataSt);
            Date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Date);
            DeviceCode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.DeviceCode);
            FreezeDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.FreezeDate);
            GasVolume = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.GasVolume);
            MeterRTC = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.MeterRTC);
            NetID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.NetID);
            RSSI = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.RSSI);
            State = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.State);
            CommType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CommType);


        }
    }




}
```

recycler_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <LinearLayout

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/DeviceCode"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#CD0808"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Analysis"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Battery"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CommunicationAddres"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/Date"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/FreezeDate"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/GasVolume"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/MeterRTC"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/NetID"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/RSSI"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/State"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/CommType"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/DataSt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text=""
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State)' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21949)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21949)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21949)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21949)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21949)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21949)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21949)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21949)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:790)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21949)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3081)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2591)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1722)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7621)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1029)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:852)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:787)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1014)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:235)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7441)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `doInBackground` everything is executed on the background thread, while `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` are executed on UI thread.

So your recyclerview is null because you are running operation on background thread

You can add `runOnUiThread` callback inside `doInBackground` to execute things on the UI thread.

Like this

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
    ((MainActivity)getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { // executed on UI thread
            ArrayList<String> wait = new ArrayList<String>();
            wait.add("PLEASE WAIT......");
            Empty_Adpater adapter = new Empty_Adpater(getContext(), wait);
            recycler_view_grid_meter_list.setAdapter(adapter);
            recycler_view_grid_meter_list.setLayoutManager(new 
            LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok i'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: glad to hear that :)